# List all link of friends between two given Friends

Tags: javascript, node.js, graph, tree

It is said that all people on average are six, or fewer, social connections away from each other.
Create an app that helps you find the degree of separation between any two people.
Think of it as selecting two users on Facebook and trying to see how these two people are
connected.

If you select any two people, you should be able to see the
degrees of separation between them.
For example, if you have the following relationships added into your system...

- Sameer is a Friend of Aayushi
- Aayushi is a Friend of Bhaskar
- Sameer is a Friend of Kamalnath Sharma
- Kamalnath Sharma is a Friend of Shanti Kumar Saha
- Shanti Kumar Saha is a Friend of Bhaskar

If you select two people, let’s say Sameer and Bhaskar, the application should show the degree
of separation as follows.

- Sameer > Aayushi > Bhaskar
- Sameet > Kamalnath Sharma > Shanti Kumar Saha > Bhaskar

I have to implement this logic in Node.js application!
I tried different methods using graph linklist but can't find the solution to implement this.

Comment: Do you know breadth first  search? If you want to print shortest connections first that would work. Or depth first short if the order of connections don’t matter

Comment: no, I don't know breadth-first search. and I want all the possible connections ways so that they are connected.

Comment: Well, if you only ever learn 2 Graph/Tree algorithms, they should probably be Breadth First Search and Depth First Search, and since either can solve your problem now would be a great time to pick one and learn it. There are lots of resources on them to get you started. As you do your BFS/DFS just keep track of the path you've taken so far and whenever you find your target, add the path you've taken to a results array to be returned at the end. Oftentimes you stop BFS or DFS when you find the target you're looking for, but you can keep going until you process the whole graph to find all paths.

Comment: Terminology notes: BFS/DFS work by finding paths from a start vertex to an end/target vertex. So if you're looking for the connection between Sameer and Bhaskar, Sameer would be the start and Bhaskar the target. 'Path' just refers to the chain of friends you go through to connect the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the answer you posted (in the future you could probably just edit your post), you pretty much got it. You could make the DFS more efficient by preprocessing your JSON into an adjacency list Graph, and you could avoid infinite loops by keeping track of which friends you've visited before (so you don't visit them multiple times and loop around infinitely).

An adjacency list Graph is just a representation of a Graph where you store in an object a list of vertices as keys, and a list of all other vertices they're adjacent (connected) to as the values. For example, the Graph would have the key `"sameer"` mapped to the list `["aayushi", "kamalnath"]`. This makes it so that every time you call `find`, you don't have to loop over all of `Data` to find `value1`. You could just find the friends of `value1` by doing `Graph[value1]`. (I renamed `value1` to `source` and `value2` to `target` along with a few other variable name changes in the code below for clarity).

As for avoiding loops, you can track friends you've already visited in a simple javascript Object (or set), initialized as empty and added to as you visit each new friend at the start of the recursive call, then just pass this Object down each recursive call. You check it at the start of each call to make sure you aren't entering into a loop. This isn't necessary for DFS/BFS searches you perform on trees (which are by definition acyclic Graphs), but it's needed for general Graphs which might have loops/cycles.

One other minor thing is when you find your target value/friend, you have

```
if(Data[i].friends[j] == value2){
  path.push(Data[i].friends[j])
  break;
}
```

You're right not to recurse in this case, but you probably don't want to break if you want to be able to continue to search the other friends you're looping over for alternate paths (rather than just breaking and returning the first path you find).

Also, I'm not sure if this is intentional, but in the example data it looks like friendships are one-way (eg shanti is a friend of bhaskar, but bhaskar has no listed friends). If they're meant to be 2 way you would probably change how you preprocess the connections list into a Graph slightly. Anyways, here is code with all the changes I mentioned. If it's not clear let me know:

```js
// preprocess a JSON list of connections to an adjacency list Graph
function connectionsListToGraph(connections) {
  const Graph = {}
  for (let { name, friends } of connections) {
    Graph[name] = friends // allow fast lookup of a given person's friends
  }
  return Graph
}

// return the list of connections between source and target
function getConnections(source, target, connections) {

  const Graph = connectionsListToGraph(connections)
  const connectionPaths = []

  function findConnectionsDFS(source, target, path = [source], visited = {}) {
    // Don't search/visit the same friend twice (to avoid infinite loops)
    if (visited[source]) return; 

    // mark that we've searched the current source friend
    visited[source] = true; 

    for (let friend of Graph[source]) {
      if (friend === target) {
        connectionPaths.push(path.concat(target));
      } else {
        findConnectionsDFS(friend, target, path.concat(friend), visited)
      }
    }
  }
  findConnectionsDFS(source, target);
  return connectionPaths;
}

let connections = [
  {
    "name": "sameer",
    "friends": ["aayushi", "kamalnath"]
  },
  {
    "name": "aayushi",
    "friends": ["bhaskar"]
  },
  {
    "name": "kamalnath",
    "friends": ["shanti"]
  },
  {
    "name": "shanti",
    "friends": ["bhaskar"]
  }
]

console.log('Sameer to Bhaskar:', getConnections('sameer', 'bhaskar', connections))
console.log('Kamalnath to Bhaskar:', getConnections('kamalnath', 'bhaskar', connections))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I am currently learning DSA and I have not even started trees.                           your solution really helps me to understand the question better and now I am little less scare of graph.

Answer (score 0):

**I used recursion I tried DFS but I was not able to implement it**
I was taking data in basic JSON and updating it on the go as this function can be in an infinite loop if the question did not specify that there will be your target value under 6 connections of friends.

```json
[
  {
    "name": "samer",
    "friends": ["aayushi", "kamalnath"]
  },
  {
    "name": "aayushi",
    "friends": ["bhaskar"]
  },
  {
    "name": "kamalnath",
    "friends": ["shanti"]
  },
  {
    "name": "shanti",
    "friends": ["bhaskar"]
  }
]
```

```js
function find(value1,value2,path){
if(count > 6)
  while(true){
  for(var i in Data){
   if(Data[i].name == value1){
     for(var j in Data[i].friends){
        if(Data[i].friends[j] == value2){
            path.push(Data[i].friends[j])
            break;
           }
        else{
            find(Data[i].friends[j],value2,path)
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}}
```

```js
var path = [];
find("samer","bhaskar",path,6)

//Output --> [[aayushi],[kamalnath,shanti]]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).